# When to use both BelongsTo and HasMany?

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm, has-many, belongs-to

I use an ORM in Golang (GORM) and I am trying to understand if (and when) I should use **both** HasMany and BelongsTo relationships.

I understand that using:

- HasMany allows me to query the children elements from the level of the parent
- BelongsTo is the other way round, where I can query the parent of a child element

Is there a case where it is needed or recommended to have both relationships? (given that they are redundant)

Comment: They aren't redundant. The popup of the `belongs-to` tag explains the difference. Belongs to literally means that the object belongs to or is owned by another, so when that parent object is deleted, the owned objects also have to be deleted. It's more strict that a reverse navigation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thank you for the comment. What I do not understand is that `has-many` also links a parent to elements. Is the cascading of delete the only difference then? (and BTW I explicitly did not tag `go` or `gorm` because I wanted to keep it a generic ORM question (where the concepts are used across languages)

Comment: The difference is *ownership*. It means a child can't exist without the parent. That translates to `cascade delete` in SQL. My doctor has many patients. That's a has-many but doesn't imply ownership. The patients can exist without the doctor

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thank you. You provided a clear explanation I could not find in the various pages I went through. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so I can accept it? I also get from that that having both relationships at the same time (in the two directions) is not interesting.

Answer (score 0):

- hasMany means a parent can have 0, 1 or more children. Parent or children can exist indedependtly.
- belongsTo means a child belongs to exactly 1 parent. Child cannot exist without parent. Although, parent can still exist independently.

It have be helpful where we have some complex queries involved. Generally, *onetoone* and *onetomany* can be handled easily by any one of them. But, we can make our db query more efficient by utilizing both of them.

For example, User and CreditCard : A user can have multiple credit cards, a credit card belongs to a single user.

```
User (id uuid, credit_cards []CreditCards)

CreditCard(id uuid, user_id uuid, user User)
```

Query -> Get all credit cards of a user with id = uid.

- Way 1: Traverse CreditCard table with condition userId = uid and return all.
- Way 2: As we are also having hasMany, we can directly query in User table with id = uid and return CreditCards. It may be more efficient.